# Writing XML to the drive in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, for-xml-path

I'm having a hard time working out how to write XML to my hard drive in SQL Server. I gather I could do something like this:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "@@@INSERT SELECT/FOR XML QUERY@@@" queryout "C:\test.xml" -T -c -t'
```

But my SELECT/FOR XML query runs to about 40 lines so I'd rather not. I tried storing the XML as @storedXML, saving it in a table and then querying that table with bcp:

```
CREATE TABLE xmlOutput(outXML xml)
INSERT INTO xmlOutput(outXML)
VALUES (@storedXML)

DECLARE @sqlCmd VARCHAR(1000)
SET @sqlCmd = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM xmlOutput" queryout C:\test.xml -c -T -t'
EXEC xp_cmdshell @sqlCmd
```

But all that gets me is "Unable to open BCP host data-file".

Comment: Have you seen this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619061/unable-to-open-bcp-host-data-file

Comment: Have you considered putting your 40 lines of code in a stored procedure then using `bcp "exec myDB.dbo.myProcedure" queryout "C:\test.xml" -T -c`?

Comment: Thank you - the stored procedure eventually did the trick, after I sorted out further issues involving folder permissions. It was also necessary to include -S and my server/instance name.